# Segmentation fault is reported when running directly, but runs normally in Debug mode

Tags: python-3.x

When I run directly my python files, it report segmentation fault, but it runs normally in Debug mode. This is my code,the pdf file contains image and text. This is my final project.

This code is based on unstructured core library and processes pdf files. I think the problem occurs with the patipation function.

```
import tempfile

import pandas as pd
from unstructured.chunking.title import chunk_by_title
from unstructured.cleaners.core import clean, group_broken_paragraphs
from unstructured.documents.elements import (
    CompositeElement,
    Footer,
    Header,
    Image,
    Table,
)
from unstructured.partition.auto import partition

from tools.vision import vision_completion

pdf_name = "raw/test.pdf"

min_image_width = 250
min_image_height = 270

elements = partition(
    filename=pdf_name,
    pdf_extract_images=True,
    pdf_image_output_dir_path=tempfile.gettempdir(),
    skip_infer_table_types=["jpg", "png", "xls", "xlsx"],
    strategy="hi_res",
)

filtered_elements = [
    element
    for element in elements
    if not (isinstance(element, Header) or isinstance(element, Footer))
]

for element in filtered_elements:
    if element.text != "":
        element.text = group_broken_paragraphs(element.text)
        element.text = clean(
            element.text,
            bullets=False,
            extra_whitespace=True,
            dashes=False,
            trailing_punctuation=False,
        )
    # elif isinstance(element, Image):
    #     point1 = element.metadata.coordinates.points[0]
    #     point2 = element.metadata.coordinates.points[2]
    #     width = abs(point2[0] - point1[0])
    #     height = abs(point2[1] - point1[1])
    #     if width >= min_image_width and height >= min_image_height:
    #         element.text = vision_completion(element.metadata.image_path)

chunks = chunk_by_title(
    elements=filtered_elements,
    multipage_sections=True,
    combine_text_under_n_chars=0,
    new_after_n_chars=None,
    max_characters=4096,
)

text_list = []
for chunk in chunks:
    if isinstance(chunk, CompositeElement):
        text = chunk.text
        text_list.append(text)
    elif isinstance(chunk, Table):
        if text_list:
            text_list[-1] = text_list[-1] + "\n\n" + chunk.metadata.text_as_html
        else:
            text_list.append(chunk.metadata.text_as_html)
result_list = []

for text in text_list:
    split_text = text.split("\n\n", 1)
    if len(split_text) == 2:
        title, body = split_text
        result_list.append({"title": title, "body": body})

df = pd.DataFrame(result_list)
print(df)
df.to_excel("output/output.xlsx", index=True, header=True)





I tried commenting out these two lines, it can run normally
```

Comment: use the **full path name**...